# Ansible playbook missing hosts in HTML report when using parallel execution (serial)

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have an Ansible playbook that runs on a large number of hosts (around 800) to generate an HTML report containing hostnames. The playbook is intended to run in parallel on all hosts.

When I set the serial parameter to a value like 500 or higher, the resulting HTML report contains fewer entries than expected (e.g., only 500 hosts). However, when I set serial: 1, I get all the entries in the report. While serial: 1 works, it's not a feasible solution as I want the playbook to run on all hosts concurrently.

Here's a simplified version of my playbook:

```
- name: Tail Logs and Generate Report
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  ignore_unreachable: yes
  serial: 500  # The issue occurs with higher values

  tasks:
    - name: create header html
      lineinfile:
         path: /reports/daily_report.html
         line: "<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <style>table{border-collapse:collapse;width:100%}td,th{border:1px solid #000;padding:8px;text-align:left}</style><title>Daily Report Details</title> </head> <body> <h1>Daily Report Details</h1> <table> <thead>
      <tr> 
      <th>PG Host Name</th>
      </tr> 
      </thead> <tbody>"
      create: yes
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
      ignore_errors: yes

    - name: Write content in report
      lineinfile:
      path: /reports/daily_report.html
      line: "<tr> 
          <td> {{ inventory_hostname }}</td>
          </tr>"
      insertafter: EOF
      delegate_to: localhost
      ignore_errors: yes
      no_log: true

    - name: create footer html
      lineinfile:
      path: /reports/daily_report.html
      line: "</tbody> </table> </body> </html>"
      delegate_to: localhost
      ignore_errors: yes
      run_once: true
```

I've tried debugging, checking host iteration logic, and reviewing error messages, but I'm unable to identify the root cause. The playbook seems to run fine in parallel with a lower serial value.

Could someone help me understand why increasing the serial value results in missing hosts in the HTML report? Are there any best practices or considerations when using high values for serial in Ansible playbooks?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please update your question to include a minimal playbook that reproduces the question you're asking about. Without seeing the code, we can only guess about what's happening.

Comment: How about just gathering minimal facts incl. fact caching and generate the report afterwards from cached facts? Almost no tasks necessary. In my opinion that would be much much simpler.

Comment: @larsks I've updated the playbook and added few tasks which generate the html report. Please take a look

Comment: @U880D Can you please provide an example for your suggestion? I'm a newbie in ansible, so unable to get it

Comment: I am not fully understand what you try to achieve. Because of the usage of `hosts: all` and `{{ inventory_hostname }}` you would just generate a file with all hosts from inventory. Couldn't you use in example just `ansible-inventory all --graph`? What is the daily report really about? Hosts you can reach and connect to over the network? Because with the currently given information this seems not be the case for me.

Comment: @U880D I've just added a sample code, there are lot more tasks which I've not added. Basically this playbook goes to all the hosts, read some log files and print those hostnames and logs in the report which will further be used for monitoring purpose. So it's very essential to have details of all the hosts of inventory in the report

Comment: "_... there are lot more tasks which I've not added. Basically this playbook goes to all the hosts, read some log files and print those hostnames and logs in the report ..._", ah, I see. Looks like you are implementing functionality which is already there out-of-box, known as [Custom facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#adding-custom-facts).

Comment: Apart from just reading logs, there are few more tasks which give the output at runtime. So, it would be better if we go ahead and try to find the root cause of the question asked

Comment: "_So, it would be better if we go ahead and try to find the root cause of the question asked_", indeed, it seems to be a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/394576), at least for me, mostly caused by the description of your Use Case. And additionally, why would one like to implement functionality which is already there out-of-box? Anyway, someone else will have an idea how to implement that ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding **throttle: 1** helped to resolve the issue. This helps to run a particular task one by one for all servers and not simultaneously. Simultaneous execution on all servers was probably causing the problem. Please [refer](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#restricting-execution-with-throttle) for more info.

```
- name: Tail Logs and Generate Report
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  ignore_unreachable: yes

  tasks:
    - name: create header html
      lineinfile:
         path: /reports/daily_report.html
         line: "<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <style>table{border-collapse:collapse;width:100%}td,th{border:1px solid #000;padding:8px;text-align:left}</style><title>Daily Report Details</title> </head> <body> <h1>Daily Report Details</h1> <table> <thead>
      <tr> 
      <th>PG Host Name</th>
      </tr> 
      </thead> <tbody>"
      create: yes
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
      ignore_errors: yes

    - name: Write content in report
      lineinfile:
      path: /reports/daily_report.html
      line: "<tr> 
          <td> {{ inventory_hostname }}</td>
          </tr>"
      insertafter: EOF
      delegate_to: localhost
      ignore_errors: yes
      no_log: true
      throttle: 1

    - name: create footer html
      lineinfile:
      path: /reports/daily_report.html
      line: "</tbody> </table> </body> </html>"
      delegate_to: localhost
      ignore_errors: yes
      run_once: true
```